# Can someone provide an explanation as to why this question was closed as Off-Topic?

Tags: discussion

https://superuser.com/questions/1780499/how-to-apply-change-to-auto-correct-setting-on-onenote-for-the-web-persistently

The only thing I can think of is if it was mistaken for a question about a Microsoft product in the context of being answerable only by an internal staff member of Microsoft; however, the actual context of the question is regarding TamperMonkey .js scripts?  Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: The web version of OneNote would belong at [webapps.se]. It was originally migrated there but a mod at that site rejected the migration by closing it there. You should ask at their meta why they do not believe it to be on topic.

Comment: I do not know why this meta question was migrated here except for it being about your Super User question rather than the webapps [migration stub](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/170312/how-to-apply-change-to-auto-correct-setting-on-onenote-for-the-web-persistently?noredirect=1). The question is entirely about the webapp, does not appear to be about the browser and [Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey scripts are explicitly on topic there.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) I would post your actual question on [webapps.se] and then challenge if it gets closed.

Comment: Due to the volume of wrongly posted and wrongly closed questions, there is now a stack overflow dedicated to helping posters work out which site to post to, and how to word their question so as not to trigger admins. For posters who've had questions closed for no obvious reason, you can also ask how best to explain to admins why the question is on topic. There is also content on the definition of key terms like "opinion" and "software". Please try asking there and you should be able to figure out where to post or how to word your question; https://ubermeta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @NeilG  Part of me was hoping that there was actually an SE site for that.

Comment: @NeilG Maybe you're onto something, this could be the start of something great 

Answer (score 2):

Web Applications mod here who migrated this question from Web Applications Meta.

The question was migrated here because it explicitly asks why
`https://superuser.com/questions/1780499/how-to-apply-change-to-auto-correct-setting-on-onenote-for-the-web-persistently` was closed. Please note that URL domain is the domain of Super User.

Not all questions about web applications and TamperMonkey are a good fit for Web Applications. For details see [What kind of questions can I ask here? The detailed version](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/894/88163).

I already left a couple of comments on the question in focus. I just read again your reply to my comments.

Current status of your question: It's too broad. I don't think that it's a good fit for any Stack Exchange site. You might need a mentor or you could make a self-learning plan.

At this time Stack Exchange hasn't an official or endorsed mentoring program.

You might ask for help with how to create a self-learning plan in [Computer Science Educators](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com). Ref. [How to point "learners" to this site?](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/514/12659)

## Related

- [As of today, April 2023, who do we understand is our intended audience and what is the first that we tell them about how to participate?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5012/88163)

Comment: I cited the SU post's URI because in all technicality, that *was* the original post (to retain traceability).  That post was migrated to Web Apps, whereupon it was closed; I didn't realize I would need to specify that I was asking regarding the Web Apps closure when I specifically posted to Web Apps Meta.

Comment: "Not all questions about web applications and TamperMonkey are a good fit for Web Applications."  Can you elaborate what criteria would qualify/disqualify a post?  I looked at the FAQ and did not see anything that stood out to this regard; rather, it appears to be on-topic according to what I read?  As for the question being "too broad", can you also elaborate on this?  I explicitly stated the *exact* setting in question that I wanted to toggle on, down to the *exact* checkbox with HTML, xpath, and related info.  I'm not sure how much more specificity is needed to qualify the question?

Comment: Brevity sometimes works, other times doesn't. Regarding your request to elaborate, I don't think that I should do this here as comments should not be used to have lengthy discussions and follow-up questions should be posted as new questions. I suggest that your follow-up question asks for a site recommendation. IMO it should be posted in [meta.se].